# minDate validation based on field value in angular reactive form validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have created a form which contains admissionDate and birthDate, I want the minDate to be birthDate, I have used RxwebValidators form  @rxweb package for validating the fields

Component.ts

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

    employeeFormGroup: FormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.employeeFormGroup= this.formBuilder.group({
          admissionDate :['',RxwebValidators.required()],
          birthDate:['',RxwebValidators.minDate({value:'28/01/2019'}]
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any way through which i can validate admissionDate based upon the birthDate

Comment: validate admissionDate based upon the birthDate? what kind of validation you want to implement? RxWebValidators have compare, greaterThan, greaterThanEqualTo etc validators. Please explain your scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @Obaid I want to validate admissionDate based on another field that is birthDate should be the minimum date ...RxWebValidators also have minDate and maxDate

Comment: @AvniPatel, RxWebValidators minDate https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators#mindate required a dateobject, so must be some like minDate({value:newDate(2019,0,28)}) -or minDate({value:new Date("2019-01-28")})